# Size Mismatch for Functional Linear Layer

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I apologize that this is probably a simple question that has been answered before, but I could not find the answer. I’m attempting to use a CNN to extract features and then input that into a FC network that outputs 2 variables. I’m attempting to use the functional linear layer as a way to dynamically handle the flattened features. The `self.cnn` is a Sequential container which last layer is the `nn.Flatten()`. When I print the size of x after the CNN I see it is 15x152064, so I’m unclear why the `F.linear` layer is failing to run with the error below. Any help would be appreciated.

RuntimeError: size mismatch, get 15, 15x152064,2

```
x = self.cnn(x)
batch_size, channels = x.size()
x = F.linear(x, torch.Tensor([256,channels]))
y_hat = self.FC(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.Tensor([256, channels])` does not create a tensor of size `(256, channels)` but the 1D tensor containing the values 256 and `channels` instead. I don't know how you want to initialize your weights, but there are a couple options :

```
# Identity transform:
x = F.linear(x, torch.ones(256,channels))
# Random transform :
x = F.linear(x, torch.randn(256,channels))
```